# NSObject subclass locations

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.2

I am currently trying to add a class to my iOS application and I need to find a NSObject subclass. The directions say that it will be located within the cocoatouch but is not. What is in there are; Objective-C class, Objective-c Category, Objective-c class extensions, Objective -c protocol, does anyone know where I can find this subclass file?

Answer (score 2):

You want Objective-C class. Then you get to choose which class to make your new class a subclass of.